# Function Definition - Don't know how to find

Tags: emacs, elisp

I use SlimeNav to read elisp code. It works good mostly, but for inbuilt functions, at times, it does not work.

```
(local-file (file-relative-name 
                       temp-file 
                       (file-name-directory buffer-file-name))))
```

In this snippet, when i press Alt + . on `local-file` function, it says,

```
Don't know how to find 'local-file'
```

Answer (score 3):

`local-file` is not a function anywhere in the core. It's used as a let-bound variable 7 times though.
Maybe you confused it.

Answer (score 0):

Also remember that when accessing the documentation on a function (eg with C-h f), you should see a link you can click to get to the source code. Works also with the C sources if they are available in a way Emacs can find.

As an example, the documentation for find-file looks like this:

```
find-file is an interactive compiled Lisp function in `files.el'.

It is bound to <open>, C-x C-f, <menu-bar> <file> <new-file>.

(find-file FILENAME &optional WILDCARDS)

Edit file FILENAME.
...
```

You should be able to see that `files.el' comes out in a different colour, this you can click and it will bring you to the definition of that function.